# Find out which event types are available

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, dom-events, vendor-prefix

In meteor the following event handler should be triggered when a css3 transition ends:

```
Template.flipper.events({
    "transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd": function (event) {
        console.log(this, event);
    }
});
```

However it does not seem accept multiple event types.

The following works fine on Google Chrome however:

```
Template.flipper.events({
    "webkitTransitionEnd": function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

I could assign the events separately as follows:

```
function transitionEnd(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

Template.flipper.events({
    transitionend: transitionEnd,
    webkitTransitionEnd: transitionEnd,
    oTransitionEnd: transitionEnd,
    MSTransitionEnd: transitionEnd
});
```

But now, on some browser version that support `transitionend` without the vender-prefix the event will fire twice.

I would like to find out which even-type is supported so that I can do something like this:

```
var flipperEvents = {};

flipperEvents[supportedEvents("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd")] = function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});

Template.flipper.events(flipperEvents);
```

Now how would I implement the function `supportedEvents` that would return `"transitionend"` for the more modern browsers and the vender-prefixed version otherwise?

I would prefer to not use browser type detection in order to evaluate what prefix to use.

Isn't there some place I can look up what even types are supported?

I know it could be easily done in jQuery, but I am trying to avoid jQuery for this one.

### Update

I've tried to use the [method found here](https://github.com/EvandroLG/transitionEnd/blob/master/src/transition-end.js):

```
var transitions = {
    'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
    'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
    'transition': 'transitionEnd',
    'MSTransition': 'msTransitionEnd',
    'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd'
};


Template.flipper.rendered = function () {
    var flipper = this.find(".flipper"),
        eventMap = {},
        eventType;

    for (type in transitions) {
        if (type in flipper.style) {
            eventType = transitions[type];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (eventType) {
        eventMap[eventType] = function (event) {
            console.log(event);
        };

        console.log(eventMap);

        Template.flipper.events(eventMap);
    }

    transitions = {};
};
```

But that doesn't work either. I think it is because Meteor does not allow event maps after a template was rendered.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid jQuery? It's there under Meteor anyway.

Comment: @HubertOG Because I want to constrain things to the template's landmark. I can get the context from Spark when using jQUery, but I cannot do queries for a particular landmark.

Answer (score 0):

I was not enabled to create a function as universal as `supportedEvents`, but the following achieves the goal:

```
var transitions = {
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionEnd',
        'MSTransition': 'msTransitionEnd',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd'
    },
    probe = document.createElement("div"),
    eventType;

for (type in transitions) {
    if (type in probe.style) {
        eventType = transitions[type];
        break;
    }
}

if (eventType) {
    var eventMap = {};

    eventMap[eventType] = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    };

    Template.flipper.events(eventMap);
}
```

Works in Chrome and Mozilla so far. Haven't tested other browsers yet.